# Inserting a web page in an OpenOffice Writer document and keeping (some) style

Tags: html, openoffice

I'm writing a report for school and I would like to include a html document as an appendix. So far all my attempts have resulted in a seriously malformed appearance. The results are hardly readable and certainly not presentable.

Is there a convenient way to insert an html document into an OpenOffice Writer document while keeping a decent look?

Comment: When you say "a decent look", do you mean (a) similar to the style of the report as a whole or (b) similar to the style of the original webpage?

Comment: @new123456 Similar to the style of the web page. I'm wondering if it's possible to insert an html file into the Writer document and have it look the same way it looks in a browser. Of course the rest of the file is a standard .odf (OpenOffice Writer document) and not an web page.

Comment: You could create a screenshot and insert it as picture. There are different browser Add-Ons allowing to customize the screenshot. So the question might be browser-related primarily, not OOo / LibreOffice.

Comment: @tohuwawohu is probably right here. The other option, depending on how you want to go, is to print the website as a PDF (Chrome and probably Firefox can do this for you) and import the PDF into OpenOffice. The difference between the PDF method and the image method, is that PDF does a better job when scaling text; that is to say, a PDF will tend _not_ to get pixelated as you scale it up.